# Can data from a subquery be used in the outer query?

Tags: mysql, subquery

Sorry for the poor question title, I'm not sure if there's a name for what I'm trying to do.

I would like to have a query such as the following:

```
SELECT a, b, c, (d + e - f) as computedValue,

(SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table2) as d,
(SELECT SUM(column2) FROM table3) as e,
(SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table4) as f,

FROM table1
WHERE a = 1
```

So, in other words, I would like to use integer values returned from subqueries to compute a value. I can do this in PHP like this:

```
$computedValue = $row['d'] + $row['e'] - $row['f'];
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in the query itself?

When I tried I got the following error:

> Error!: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'd' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use column aliases in most clauses of the same query, including in the select-list.
This seems puzzling for many SQL developers, but that's standard SQL.

But you can use a **derived table** subquery like this:

```
SELECT *, (d + e - f) as computedValue 
FROM (
    SELECT a, b, c,    
    (SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table2) as d,
    (SELECT SUM(column2) FROM table3) as e,
    (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table4) as f    
    FROM table1
    WHERE a = 1
) AS x;
```

Answer (score 1):

A Select statements fields can contain other select statements as fields. You can then do your mathematics on those selected values and then assign to a column name via `AS`.

```
SELECT a, b, c, 
   (
       (SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table2) +
       (SELECT SUM(column2) FROM table3) -
       (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table4)
   ) as computedValue
FROM table1
WHERE a = 1;
```

Comment: On SO we request that all answers come with explanations, not just dis-embodied lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

As `d`,  `e` and `f` are scalar values, you could introduce user-defined variables to hold the values and use them to perform your calculations:

```
SELECT a, b, c,

@d := (SELECT SUM(column1) FROM table2) as d,
@e := (SELECT SUM(column2) FROM table3) as e,
@f := (SELECT SUM(column3) FROM table4) as f,

(@d + @e - @f) as computedValue

FROM table1
WHERE a = 1
```

Comment: MySQL tends to evaluate select-list expressions from left to right, so in your example the `computedValue` will use values from the previous  row.

Comment: Yep, moving the `computedValue` expression to *after* the other user variables are assigned values should work.  I'm not sure MySQL *guarantees* that order of evaluation anywhere in their docs, but it works in my experience.

Comment: @BillKarwin ... :( as a matter of fact, they explicitly warn against that: "As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement" ... "For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed." ... but as you said, *empirically* it works.

Comment: Yes, basically, "don't get mad at us if we change the implementation in a future version of MySQL and your query breaks."  ;-)